# How to synchronize hour between two Win7 machines to have the same timestamp

Tags: datetime, boost, time, mfc, ntp

I developed a MFC application in C++ which I use to capture data from some USB sensors in order to save the information in a TXT file. For each data, I also save the timestamp with boost function.

I need to use my application also with another pc since I have to acquire data twice and I'd like to know what's the best method to synchronize the data between these two pcs.

I'm using the first pc to create a Wifi network and I'm able to connect the second pc to the first one and then I'm trying to use "net time" to set the NTP service without success.

Is there any tutorial or someone which can explain me how to synchronize date time between two Win7 pcs, please?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this command? Run from the cmd prompt.

```
net time \\MasterPC /set /yes
```

where MasterPC is the network name of the computer you want to take the time from.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input! Unfortunately, if I type that command, my client pc says: System Error 1450 or System Error 5.

Comment: Try running the cmd prompt with administrator privileges? To do that type cmd in the start menu, wait till cmd.exe appears and right click "run as administrator"

Comment: I was already trying to run cmd with admin privileges with success.

I'm able to execute this command on each machine "net time \\LocalPcName" but I can't run the command you suggested.

In particular, I can't access remote time information but only the local one.

Comment: I've used something similar before but it just worked. Perhaps disable firewall issue on the remote PC? It's probably not that but I'm out of advice at this point.